# Jquery click event is fired on document load

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head></head>

  <body>
    <div id="someElement">
      <button id="someButton">Click Me</button>
    </div>
    <script src="jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script src="backbone-min.js"></script>
    <script>
      MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
        events: {
          "click #someButton": "clicked"
        },
        clicked: function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          alert("I was clicked!");
        },
        render: function () {
          var html = "generate some HTML, here";
          $(this.el).html(html);
        }
      });

      $(function () {
        var myView = new MyView();
        myView.render();
        $("#someElement").html(myView.el);
      });
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LfGtu/

My question is: how do I wait for a click on the button to fire the click event?

(by the way, code partly comes from http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/11/09/backbone-js-object-literals-views-events-jquery-and-el/ )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An alternative to adding a jQuery click event would be to move the render method out of the jQuery onReady event and into the click-handler "clicked" that's already in your code. You just need to pass '#someElement' as your 'el' property when you create the view.

Made a quick jsBin demo here: http://jsbin.com/ugafod/4

This approach seems more "Backbone-ish" but both ways work fine.

Comment: Thanks. That is what I was looking for. A backbone-ish approach.

Answer (score 2):

What button? Your `render` event changes `#someElement` content. Your button is gone before it can be clicked.

Comment: +1 This is actually correct. The HTML is replaced in the example, so there is no button!

Answer (score 1):

You've used a self-invoking function. That's it nature - the browser will run the function as soon as it loads that part of the html page. If you want to defer it, you need to associate it with an action, such as:

```
$('my div or button or whatever you like').click(function(){
    // Function to run here.
});
```

I've created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wigster/ha29r/) for you. This should be what you are after.

Comment: $(function () {
        var myView = new MyView();
        myView.render();
        $("#someElement").html(myView.el);
      });

^ Is self invoking.
[Good explanation of self invoking functions](http://sarfraznawaz.wordpress.com/2012/01/26/javascript-self-invoking-functions/)

Comment: Yes it is, but that's the DOM ready function, it better be self invoking!

Comment: it's not self-invoking function: `$(function(){...});` is equivalent to `$(document).ready(function(){...});`

Comment: I've created a jsFiddle for you in my original post, I think it's what you're after :).